# Proteus/Ares 8 - why does adding ground plane not make ground links disappear?

Tags: proteus, ground-plane

I have a 2 layer through hole board I am laying out with lots of ground pins showing as ratsnest routing links. However, when I add the reverse copper as a ground plane using: 
tools/power plane generator
with net (GND=POWER)
and layer (Bottom Copper)
I see only a blue outline near the edge of the board (the ground plane I assume?) and the GND rats nest remains.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some sort of copper pour button?

Comment: Sort of, but that seems to define separate areas of ground plane. The above defines the whole of the solder side as ground, which I assume is enough.

Comment: Does the tool recalculate ratlines after every edit? Or is there a "re-calculate ratlines" command you have to invoke? Maybe some functions of the program re-calculate ratlines, but other functions neglect to do it?

Comment: I have only added a few components, mainly power supplies and connectors. I am routing manually.

Comment: I would try right clicking on the blue outline and see what options are available.

Comment: Already done that. Doesn't work, in any combination

Comment: Just added another ground plane within the first, and it has "stuck". So, success, but no idea why

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue while changing the power plane, a quick fix is just to delete the outline and try again. If that doesn't work maybe this article at Labcenter about 
[power planes](http://www.labcenter.com/products/pcb/pcb_zones.cfm) under ARES will be useful.